# get data between two date time cells

Tags: excel

I have DATETIME column which has (date & time) in format mm/dd/yy hh:mi( Eg: 3/19/12 0:06). I need to get the data between two DATETIME cells(Eg from 3/19/12 0:06 to 3/19/12 0:51) . The in between cells are 3/19/12 0:21 3/19/12 0:36. This pattern is same for every hour

I need formula which calculated the sum of data between these cells for every hour

Comment: Can you add a picture of your sample data and show us what you expect the "answer" to be?  This is still a little vague what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a column (eg ColumnA), if it starts in row2, ascends, and if I understand your question, then:

> =IF(MOD(ROW(),4)=1,A5-A2,"")

entered in the same row as your first latest time (of four) should work.

For each successive fourth row =MOD(ROW(),4) returns 1 and here this is used as the trigger to take the difference between the value in the A column of the corresponding row and the value three rows above that.